# TrueCrypt messes up its drive letters

Tags: windows-7, windows, truecrypt, drive-letter

For some reason, about 50% of the time when I mount a volume with TrueCrypt, it mounts to a different drive letter, forcing me to un-mount it and re-mount it to the drive letter I need.

(I mount the volumes with the shortcut key I've bound, and I do *not* use that drive letter for anything else.)

Why does this happen? Any way to prevent it from happening?

Comment: What method did you use to bind it to the shortcut key? Without that detail we won't be able to help.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Settings->Hot Keys.

Comment: Have you considered adding it to favourites? http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/favorites

Comment: I should have mentioned that when I restart Truecrypt, the drive letter highlighted by default is always the one I last dismounted. In that case, the shortcut is probably using that.

Comment: @Tog: Nope I hadn't tried (or even known) about Favorites. I'll try that now, thanks. :) (Oh, and I never use any other drive, so the last one dismounted should always be the same.)

Comment: @Tog: Yup, it seems like Favorites works, thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding it to favourites within the Truecrypt application [truecrypt.org/docs/favorites](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=favorites)